# Storing and retrieving Data from a list and a dictionary

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

-1

I'm trying to solve the following problem: Write a payroll program that stores all the user input in a list and the total of all the input in a dictionary until the user ends the program. When the program ends it will list each input given and then a total of all the input. Here is what I have so far:

```
import dates

def GetEmpName():
    empname = input("Enter employee name (END to terminate): ")
    return empname
def GetDatesWorked():
    #write the code to input fromdate and todate and return the values from the function.  
    #Prompt the user for the dates in the following format: mm/dd/yyyy
    #no validations are needed for this input, we will assume the dates are entered correctly
    fromdate = int(input("Enter the date pay period begin (mm/dd/yy): "))
    todate = int(input("Enter the date the pay period ended (mm/dd/yy): "))
   
    return fromdate, todate

def GetHoursWorked():
    hours = float(input('Enter amount of hours worked:  '))
    return hours
def GetHourlyRate():
    hourlyrate = float(input ("Enter hourly rate: "))
    return hourlyrate
def GetTaxRate():
    taxrate = float(input ("Enter tax rate: "))
    return taxrate
def CalcTaxAndNetPay(hours, hourlyrate, taxrate):
    grosspay = hours * hourlyrate
    incometax = grosspay * taxrate
    netpay = grosspay - incometax
    return grosspay, incometax, netpay

def printinfo(EmpDetailList):
    TotEmployees = 0
    TotHours = 0.00
    TotGrossPay = 0.00
    TotTax = 0.00
    TotNetPay = 0.00
    # the following code creates a for loop to read through EmpDetailList and assign values in list to variables
    for EmpList in EmpDetailList:
        fromdate = EmpList[0]
        #write code to assign values to todate, empname, hours, hourlyrate, and taxrate from EmpLst
        todate =  EmpList[1]
        empname =  EmpList[2]
        hours =  EmpList[3]
        hourlyrate = EmpList[4]
        taxrate =  EmpList[5]




        grosspay, incometax, netpay = CalcTaxAndNetPay(hours, hourlyrate, taxrate)
        print(fromdate, todate, empname, f"{hours:,.2f}",  f"{hourlyrate:,.2f}", f"{grosspay:,.2f}",  f"{taxrate:,.1%}",  f"{incometax:,.2f}",  f"{netpay:,.2f}")
        TotEmployees += 1
        TotHours += hours
        TotGrossPay += grosspay
        TotTax += incometax
        TotNetPay += netpay
        # the following line of code assigns TotEmployees totals to dictionary 
        EmpTotals["TotEmp"] = TotEmployees
        # write code to assign TotHours, TotGrossPay, TotTax, and TotNetPay to corresponding dictionary item
        EmpTotals["TotHrs"] = TotHours
        EmpTotals["TotGP"] = TotGrossPay
        EmpTotals["Tottaxes"] = TotTax
        EmpTotals["TotNP"] = TotNetPay





def PrintTotals(EmpTotals):    
    print()
    # use dictionary to print totals
    # the following line of code prints Total Employees from the dictionary
    print(f'Total Number Of Employees: {EmpTotals["TotEmp"]}')
    # write code to print TotalHrs, TotGrossPay, TotTax and TotNetPay from dictionary
    print(f'Total Hours Worked: {EmpTotals["TotHrs"]}')
    print(f'Total Gross Pay: {EmpTotals["TotGP"]}')
    print(f'Total Taxes : {EmpTotals["TotTaxes"]}')
    print(f'Total Total NetPay: {EmpTotals["TotNP"]}')
    
    
    




if __name__ == "__main__":
    #create empty list and dictionary
    EmpDetailList = []
    EmpTotals = {}
    while True:
        empname = GetEmpName()
        if (empname.upper() == "END"):
            break
        fromdate, todate = GetDatesWorked()
        hours = GetHoursWorked()
        hourlyrate = GetHourlyRate()
        taxrate = GetTaxRate()
    
        #write code to insert fromdate, todate, empname, hours, hourlyrate, and taxrate into list EmpDetail
    EmpDetail = []
    EmpDetail.expand = [fromdate, toddate, empname, hours, hourlyrate, taxrate]

        #the following code appends the list EmpDetail to the list EmpDetailList
        EmpDetailList.append(EmpDetail)

   
    printinfo(EmpDetailList)
    PrintTotals (EmpTotals)
```

My code keeps breaking first it was telling me that EmpDetail was not defined so I defined it with an empty list then added on to it. The output I expect is when the program ends it will display the following:

(Will last as many that user inputs into the program one set of employee records per line.)
Employee name, from date, to date, hours worked, hourly rate, tax rate, gross pay, taxes paid, net pay

(After all individual information is shown)
Total number of employees, total hours worked, total gross pay, total taxes paid, total net pay

Answer (score 0):

You should use class structure to store all the employee details and then loop over those objects to get individual or total statistics. You can use __ str __ (dunder method) which can help you access object of class by employee name.